# Retrieving Saved Data from Firebase - Xamarin Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I am able to save my data from my app into Firebase (Database). 
In my fragment, i populate the List_Event and inflate it into a recyclerview (Fragement3). Fragment page contains my holder and adapter. My activity page is where i am trying to do the update list for my recyclerview. I am out of ideas. Kindly help me

**Question : Now, what i want to do is, my recyclerviewer should update with the list of data entered into the database.**

**List_Event.axml in my layout folder**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:background="#E2E2E2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="7dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="25"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:id="@+id/imageView" />
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="63"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:paddingTop="7dp"
                android:paddingBottom="7dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="Event Name"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewEvent"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textSize="18sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Date and Time"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewDate"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textSize="16sp" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Venue"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewVenue"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
                <TextView
                    android:text="Description"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/textViewDescription"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:gravity="center_vertical"
                    android:padding="2dp"
                    android:textSize="14sp"
                    android:singleLine="true" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="12"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:minWidth="25px"
                android:minHeight="25px"
                android:paddingRight="5dp">
                <TextView
                    android:text="15m"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/txtTime"
                    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:paddingTop="5dp" />
                <CheckBox
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:id="@+id/cbxStart"
                    android:button="@android:drawable/btn_star" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="100"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/likeheart"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/comments"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
            <ImageButton
                android:src="@drawable/share"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="33"
                android:layout_height="25dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageButton3"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**Fragment**

```
public class Fragment3 : SupportFragment


    {

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);




            // Create your fragment here
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            RecyclerView recyclerView = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.Fragment3, container, false) as RecyclerView;

            SetUpRecyclerView(recyclerView);

            return recyclerView;
        }




        private void SetUpRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView)
        {

            //var value= GetRandomSubList(PeaceEventsCollection.GetPeaceEvents(), 5);
            var value = PeaceEventsCollection.GetPeaceEvents();

            recyclerView.SetLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(recyclerView.Context));

            var Adapter = new EventAdapter(PeaceEventsCollection.GetPeaceEvents());




        recyclerView.SetAdapter(Adapter);

            recyclerView.Click += eventClicked;

            Adapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

            recyclerView.SetItemClickListener((rv, position, view) =>
            {
                //An item has been clicked
                Context context = view.Context;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, typeof(EventDetailActivity));
                intent.PutExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_NAME,  value[position].EName);
                intent.PutExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_DETAIL, value[position].EDescritption);
                intent.PutExtra(EventDetailActivity.EXTRA_DATE, value[position].EDate);



                //perform activity to event page
                context.StartActivity(intent);
            });



        }

        private JavaList<PeaceEvents> GetRandomSubList(JavaList<PeaceEvents> items, int amount)
        {
            JavaList<PeaceEvents> list = new JavaList<PeaceEvents>();
            Random random = new Random();
            while (list.Count < amount)
            {
                list.Add(items[random.Next(items.Count)]);
            }

            return list;
        }

        private void eventClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Intent showEvent = new Intent(Context, typeof(EventActivity));
            this.StartActivity(showEvent);
        }

        public class EventAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
        {

            private JavaList<PeaceEvents> peaceEvents;

            public EventAdapter(JavaList<PeaceEvents> peaceEvents)
            {
                this.peaceEvents = peaceEvents;


            }


            public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
            {


                EventHolder hold = holder as EventHolder;
                hold.EventName.Text = peaceEvents[position].EName;
                hold.EventImg.SetImageResource(peaceEvents[position].EImage);
                hold.EventDate.Text = peaceEvents[position].EDate;
                hold.EventVenue.Text = peaceEvents[position].EVenue;
                hold.EventDescription.Text = peaceEvents[position].EDescritption;




            }


            public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
            {
                View v = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.List_Event, parent, false);
                EventHolder holder = new EventHolder(v);

                return holder;
            }

            public override int ItemCount
            {

                get { return peaceEvents.Size(); }

            }

        }
    }




    public class EventHolder : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
    {

            public TextView EventName;
            public ImageView EventImg;
            public TextView EventDate;
            public TextView EventVenue;
            public TextView EventDescription;
            public TextView textIcon;
            public TextView EventDetailDescription;


            public EventHolder(View itemView) : base(itemView)
            {
                EventName = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewEvent);
                EventImg = itemView.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
                EventDate = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDate);
                EventVenue = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewVenue);
                EventDescription = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDescription);

                //textIcon = itemView.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.textViewDate);
                //textIcon.SetCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(Resource.Drawable.ic_event, 0, 0, 0);




                //itemView.Click += itemView_Click;



            }

            //private void itemView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            //{
            //  listener(this.LayoutPosition);
            //}
        }


    }
```

**Activity**

```
private  async Task LoadData()
        {

            var firebase = new FirebaseClient(FirebaseUrl);
            var items = await firebase.Child("Games").OnceAsync<PeaceEvents>();

            peace_Events.Clear();

            EventAdapter adpater = null;




            foreach(var item in items){
                PeaceEvents events = new PeaceEvents();
                events.EName = item.Object.EName;
                events.EDate = item.Object.EDate;
                events.EDescritption = item.Object.EDescritption;
                events.EVenue = item.Object.EVenue;

                peace_Events.Add(events);



            }

            adpater = new EventAdapter(this,peace_Events);

            adpater.NotifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: is it possible i could just assign the data been passed to  adapter to the existing recycleView?

Comment: You want to update your adapter in your activity and display it with recyclerview in fragment? Then you can keep your adapter in your activity and pass it as parameter to fragment when you inflate the fragment, get this parameter in `onCreateView` and set it as adapter of your recyclerview.